# Why is minikube dns name resolving working with docker but not with rootless podman

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, podman

I use rootless podman to run minikube. With docker the services resolve. For example `<service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` yields an UnknownHostException using podman. With docker it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like installing `aardvark-dns` fixed the problem